# How to suppress column headers in AWS Athena query result?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I'm running a SELECT Athena query on an S3 bucket manifest. I then want to use the results of that query, in .csv format, in an S3 Batch operation.

My query runs fine and I am able to access the .csv output via S3 Batch, but since the first row is actually column headers, S3 Batch to throws an unrecoverable error because it thinks that the manifest is now referring to multiple buckets.

How can I easily strip the column headers out of my results? I would prefer to just do it in SQL. The file size makes using standard unix tools prohibitive. I could use AWS Glue, but this seems like overkill for just suppressing headers in a SQL query.

Comment: Hopefully somebody who knows AWS Batch will be able to assist you. For the rest of us, can you edit your question to show a sample of the manifest file with the headers you are trying to skip? Can you possibly link us to an example, or some documentation, of how the manifest is used so that we can try to reproduce your situation?

Comment: Asked the AWS Support about this a week back, since I was having the exact same problem. Their reply was that it doesn't seem possible at this time, there is no way to skip outputting headers from Athena. But they've open a feature request, so if you have enterprise support, ping your TAM to add +1 on it.

Comment: Not sure if this is still relevant but you can now skip headers by adding `"skip.header.line.count": "1"` in the `parameters`

Comment: @EthanDavis the OP is asking about how to create a query result with no header. I think what you are referring to is skipping a row while importing the source data into Athena table that OP is trying to query.

Comment: @donkz Correct but since glue is a `schema-at-read` technology it (making a gross oversimplification here) is just a view created on top of the data in S3 the header will still be there it just won't show up as a row within the view that is being queried from.

Comment: Maybe you just don't understand the problem op is having. My solution perfectly addresses it, for a fact.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a hacky way to get around it

```
SELECT bucket as "my-bucket-name", key as "fakekey"
from your_athena_table
```

This will make your header look like the rest of the file which will not break the S3 Batch copy job. You will have just one failed record of fakekey

Comment: That's... beautiful.

Comment: A note for people like me - instead of the literal string `"my-bucket-name"`, you should use an actual bucket name.

Comment: This workaround is such a beauty! Thank you so much! Just in case anyone also has the "brilliant" idea of trying out this query without any specific name for the key field (thus leaving it "") I can already tell you it won't work and it will give you this error when trying to run the Batch Job: Failed to parse task from Manifest bucket/path/xxxxx.csv at byte offset 0. ErrorMessage: Task target couldn't be URL decoded. So simply stick to donkz's solution :)